# Vertically center image when image is higher than container

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a responsive design with a header image which is placed in a container. The image has `width:100%;` and `height:auto;` so it grows as you enlarge the viewport. I don't want to exceed a certain height so the container has a `max-height`. The image still grows but now the bottom part is cut off now because it aligns to the top of the container.

I would like the image to stay **vertically centered** in it's container so that parts of the image are cut off at the top and at the bottom. The outcome should look like this:

[image: verticaly centered image]

The header images are uploaded by users so they might have different heights therefore I cannot work with specific pixel-values. Is there a CSS-solution for this or do I have to use JavaScript?

Here is the code:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-color: #E9ADAD;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300/C00000/FFFFFF&text=Image+vertically+centered">
  </div>
</div>
```

And I prepared a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghygpw8t/1/).

Comment: do you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/ghygpw8t/2/?

Comment: @amit: Thanks for the answer but that's not what I want. The picture should always fill the complete wrapper-area but with no whitespace to the left or right.

Comment: I cannot think of anything but putting the image as a background image, but I think that's not an option for you

Comment: are you looking like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ghygpw8t/6/

Comment: @Suresh Ponnukalai: Thanks for the answer, but the picture should always fill the complete wrapper-area but with no whitespace to the left or right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning for your image , negative top/bottom values and `margin:auto;` to verticaly center the image in the container :

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background-color: #E9ADAD;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.container {
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:40%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  position:absolute;
  top:-50%; bottom:-50%;
  margin:auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300/C00000/FFFFFF&text=Image+vertically+centered">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case the container always stays 200px high. I would like it to shrink as the image is getting smaller.

Comment: @zorkmedia ok, I modified my answer and used the padding technique to keep the aspect ratio of the container element, this way the container changes its height according to its width.

Comment: Thanks again, I would never have had the idea just with the padding. But I'll go with your first solution and add some break-points to my css to adjust the height of the container.

Comment: @zorkmedia my pleasure, you can also see this post for more about the padding technique http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-maintain-div-aspect-ratio

Comment: Another favorite - great knowledge.

Comment: To get it working, I just had to comment/remove the `bottom:-50%;`. Otherwise, perfect !

Answer (score 2):

Not so long ago there was only a javascript way to do this but now we have some css rules: `object-fit` and `object-position`

They work just like the background-size rules cover and contain:

```
.container img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
@supports(object-fit: cover){
    .container img{
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: center center;
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that is very new and doesn't work on ie or Edge yet.
Pen here: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/MwKKrm

EDIT: Please, see that you need to declare the width and the height of the image, or it won't work.

Comment: Thank you, I've never heard of object-fit before. Right now I do have to support IE but I'll remember this for future times.

Comment: Yes, this is a great feature and we hope that microsoft implements it for Edge! I was surprised to find this just a few weeks ago as all other solutions for this looked dirty.

Comment: Note that the *parent item* has to have a height set as well. When using `max-height` only, I couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
.container {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.imgWrapper {
    position: relative; 
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
}
img {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="imgWrapper"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ghygpw8t/5/

inspired by: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Thank you for the answer - it's almost what I'm searching for, but the container has to stay 200px high. I would like to shrink it as the image is getting smaller.

Comment: the container is staying 200px height ... i did not understand the problem

Comment: I would like the container to get smaller when the image height is smaller then 200px. That's why I set the height of my container to auto. In your solution the container always is 200px high - so there will be whitespace above and beneath the image. Meanwhile I realized that there is no perfect CSS-solution for my problem, so your solution is very close very close and a vote up. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ghygpw8t/17/)**

If image size is small it will be arranged in vertical middle and if its big, it will fit in box.

CSS:

```
 .wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
.container {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#ccc;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 200px;
    border:2px solid green;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%; 
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
img {
    width: 100%;  
    max-height: 196px;
    border:2px solid red;    
    vertical-align: middle;
     line-height: 196px;
}
```

Hope this is what you want!

Answer (score 0):

On the element you want centered.

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

on its parent.

```
.parent { transform-style: preserve-3d; }
```

Use a polyfill to render cross browser styles.